# Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I cloned the project from GitLab  and did `npm install`, it
s downloaded all the dependencies with out any issue but when I did `npm start` it is failing with  No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency this error.

I'm using node version 6.9.2 in my local.

Error:

```
18% building modules 70/104 modules 34 active ...node_modules\querystring-es3\index.jsError: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:206:21)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:195:8)
    at _this.buildModule.err (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:335:13)
    at building.forEach.cb (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:140:27)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:140:13)
    at module.build (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:167:11)
    at ContextModule.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:118:3)
    at ContextModule.result.resolveDependencies (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:224:25)
    at ContextModule.build (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:99:7)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:324:11)
    at C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModuleFactory.js:96:12
    at C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
    at done.then (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:226:28)
 18% building modules 70/105 modules 35 active ...ode_modules\webpack\buildin\global.jsC:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:264
                                if(_this.profile) {
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
    at factoryCallback (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:264:13)
    at C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:242:4
    at C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:93:13
    at C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.params.normalModuleFactory.plugin (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:272:13)
    at onDoneResolving (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:68:11)
    at onDoneResolving (C:\Users\3643585\Desktop\ecamv2\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:189:6)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fxo-ecam@0.0.2 start: `ng serve --proxy ./dev-proxies/local.proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fxo-ecam@0.0.2 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\3643585\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-06T22_57_26_745Z-debug.log
```

below is my package.json file

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fxo-ecam",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve-dev": "ng serve --environment=dev",
    "serve-release": "ng serve --environment=release",
    "serve-uat": "ng serve --environment=uat",
    "serve-staging": "ng serve --environment=staging",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy ./dev-proxies/local.proxy.conf.json",
    "startpcf": "ng serve --proxy ./dev-proxies/pcf.proxy.conf.json",
    "dev-build": "ng build --environment=dev --target=development",
    "release-build": "ng build --environment=release --target=development",
    "uat-build": "ng build --environment=uat --target=development",
    "staging-build": "ng build --environment=staging --target=development",
    "debug-build": "ng build --environment=prod --target=development --bh /ecam/components/fxo/",
    "build": "ng build --environment=prod --target=production --aot=false --bh /ecam/components/fxo/",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "tt": "ng test --browsers=Chrome --watch",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.4",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "ajv": "^5.0.0",
    "alasql": "^0.3.9",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "ng2-progressbar": "^1.3.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.38",
    "primeng": "4.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.4",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.91",
    "codelyzer": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.2.7",
    "ts-node": "^2.1.2",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of webpack version..

I got this same error, I deleted my node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and did npm install again. These steps resolved my issue.

```
1. rm -r node_modules
2. rm package-lock.json
3. npm i
```

Cheers!!

Comment: That works but I tried multiple times seems like it is inconsistent.. Any permanent solution ??